# Determine if nested object is in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am looking for a simple way of checking if a nested object exists in a list.

For example

```
example_list = [{'id':1, 'name':'k'}, {'id':2, 'name':'y'}, {'id':3, 'name':'z'}]
```

Is there a simple function that will determine if  the dict with `id=3` is in the `example_list`? I don't want to use a loop as it seems like overkill.

Comment: `If {id:3} in examplelist:` should work

Comment: Why not store them in a dictionary keyed by `'id'`, instead of a list?

Comment: That wont work because the dicts have more properties than just id.. Sorry the example was not clear

Comment: Honestly at this point it makes far more sense to restructure your dictionary such that `example_list={1: {'name':'k'},2:{'name':y}}` ...etc

Comment: @user2097159, how would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if any(x['id'] == 3 for x in example_list):
```

Of course, this assumes that all dictionaries have an `id` key.  If not, then you could do:

```
if any(x.get('id', 0) == 3 for x in example_list):
```

---

**Update:**

To get the dictionary returned, use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
dct = next((x for x in example_list if x['id'] == 3), None)
```

I made `None` the default value to return if there is no dictionary in the list which meets the criteria.  But you can pick any other value you want.

Comment: Nice. How do I return the dict after I have determined that it exists?

Comment: No advantage using a generator expression here really for a single value

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - `next` only works with iterators (which generator expressions produce).  If I used a list comprehension, I'd need to call `iter()` on it.

Comment: @iCodez, I meant it would make more sense to not call next and have the option of getting more than one dict if that was required otherwise a normal loop would actually be more efficient.

Comment: The loop is a good approach, but the OP said *"I don't want to use a loop"*.  So, I gave an alternate solution.  Besides, genexps and `next` are pretty efficient and do the job nicely in one line.  You might save a few milliseconds with a loop, but I think being concise outweighs that advantage here. :)

Comment: @iCodez, yep but technically there is a loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the first  dict that contains an `id ==`3` use a regular loop :

```
for d in example_list:
    if d.get("id") == 3:
        print(d)
        break
```

If you want all dicts use a list comp:

```
[d for  d in example_list if d.get("id") == 3]
```

You can use a function and return the dict:

```
def get_d(l, key, val):
    for d in l:
        if d.get(key) == val:
            return d
```